# Pycharm - Run code selected in running ipython console

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

In Pycharm, you can have a running iPython console after running your script with the "Show command line afterwards" option.

It is also possible to run the code selected with ALT + SHIFT + E.

But it runs the code in the Python console of Pycharm, not in the iPython console opened when running a script as described above.

Is it possible to run pieces of code likewise in that console were your script was run?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the project interpreter to IPython. Then when you execute it with `Alt + Shift + E` it will run it in IPython.

You can view how to set up an interpreter [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I am not able to do as you say. I can choose "python.exe" as interpreter, from anaconda environments etc, but not "ipython.exe" (actually it's not an interpreter, is it?). I have the option "Use iPython if available" on, and when I run my script, the console opened is iPython: "PyDev console: using IPython 6.1.0". But if I select code, do CTRL+ALT+E, it is executed in the "Python Console" of Pycharm, and not in that iPython console where my script was run and my variables are loaded. Any idea what I am doing wrong?